# Find/Replace in Eclipse with regex

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, replace

i need to replace

```
Sprite name = new Sprite(number1, number2, this.mScritteRegion.get(number3)
{
     stuff_here
};
```

where name, numberX, and stuff_here are a the part i want to keep

with

```
RectangularShape name = mLanguageManager.getSpriteWithText(number1, number2, 0, 0, "", getResources.getString(R.string.), mLanguageManager.getFont("main_font"), new IOnAreaTouched()
{
      stuff_here
});
```

So far i managed with regex to find the first part of the code, but i can't select the new line + { + stuff_here + };

Here the regex

```
Sprite (\w)* = new Sprite\((\d)*(\s)*,(\s)*(\d)*(\s)*,(\s)*this.mScritteRegion.get\((\d)*\)\)
```

and what i think i'll need to use to replce it

```
RectangularShape $1 = mLanguageManager.getSpriteWithText\($2, $5, 0, 0, "", getResources.getString\(R.string.\), mLanguageManager.getFont\("main_font"\), new IOnAreaTouched\(\) $X\)
```

i put $X because i still don't know what index it will be, in addition i don't know how to handle the }; to });. I must get stuff_here until };, because it is the only delimiter that grants me to catch everything, but i don't know then how to put the parenthesis in between them..

I just started today looking ad regex, so i'm a total noob in this field..

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in NetBeans, I figure the regex must look the same, maybe the substitution characters are different (I will check when I have access to a computer with Eclipse).

The regex to catch your first String is:

```
(?s)Sprite (\w+) = new Sprite\((\w+), (\w+),.*?(.\{.*?\});
```

The substitution regex is

```
RectangularShape $1 = mLanguageManager.getSpriteWithText($2, $3, 0, 0, "", getResources.getString(R.string.), mLanguageManager.getFont("main_font"), new IOnAreaTouched()$4);
```

A few remarks:

- the (?s) flag means that the dot (.) can be matched to a new line character
- there is one assumption here: the `};` sequence must not appear in the `stuff_here` block
- this transformation loses the new line character at the end of the signature - the semantics are the same though, and you can bring it back with formatting templates.

So, the source being:

```
Sprite name = new Sprite(number1, number2, this.mScritteRegion.get(number3)
{
  stuff_here
};
```

I get:

```
RectangularShape name = mLanguageManager.getSpriteWithText(number1, number2, 0, 0, "", getResources.getString(R.string.), mLanguageManager.getFont("main_font"), new IOnAreaTouched()   {
         stuff_here
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! (Un)fortunately i can't try it since i already replaced it by hand. Yes, it was a bit tedious, but it didn't stole more than 1h, and since i was having no response i decided to do it by hand.. I'm curious if you can tell me how to replace stuff_here even if it has }; inside it...

Comment: @Makers_F I think it would be difficult. You would need to write a regex for matching brackets. Regular expressions are meant to define regular grammars (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar), and the "bracket" grammar is not regular. But maybe I am missing something.